# How to create a localhost server to run an AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs

I have used XAMPP and JetBrains WebStorm to run an AngularJS project. But it's complicated and has low performance. Is there any other way to run an AngularJS project?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

If you're running node.js [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) is a super easy way to serve local files.

`cd` into your project folder and

```sh
npx http-server -o 

# or, install it separately so you don't need npx
npm install -g http-server
http-server -o
```

`-o` is to open browser to the page. Run `http-server --help` to view other options such as changing the port number

#### Don't have `node`?

[these other one-liners](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255) might be easier if you don't have `node`/`npm` installed.

For example python comes preinstalled on most systems, so [John Doe's python servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35211824/4522100) below would be quicker.

MacOS comes installed with ruby, so this is another easy option if you're running a Mac:
`ruby -run -ehttpd . -p8000` and open your browser to `http://localhost:8000`.

Answer (score 37):

Python has a built-in command specifically for spinning up a webserver:

Python3.x:

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

Other versions:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Would start a webserver on port 8000

(Python is a prerequisite to this; if you don't have python installed, the other answers may be easier)

Comment: It worths noting that this command serves the content of the current directory

Comment: Oh, and for Python 3 it should be `python -m http.server 8000`

Answer (score 21):

You can begin by installing Node.js from terminal or cmd:

```
apt-get install nodejs-legacy npm
```

Then install the dependencies:

```
npm install
```

Then, start the server:

```
npm start
```

Comment: NodeJS has an installer for Windows. You can download it at nodejs.org

Comment: is there any possible to start node server automatically by turn on the system

Comment: @AmarSyla, i don't know about bash profile. Can you tell me how to implement that.

Answer (score 6):

cd `<your project folder>` (where your angularjs's deployable code is there)

> sudo npm install serve -g
>
> serve

You can hit your page at

localhost:3000 or IPaddress:3000

Answer (score 5):

I use:

- express and
- morgan

Install Node.js. and npm. npm is installed with Node.js

Placed inside the root project directory

```
$ cd <your_angularjs_project>
```

The next command creates package.json

```
$ npm init
```

Install express ==> Fast, unopinionated, minimalist for node:

```
$ npm install express --save
```

Install morgan ==> HTTP request logger middleware for node.js

```
$ npm install morgan --save
```

create file server.js

add the following code in server.js file

```
// Required Modules
var express    = require("express");
var morgan     = require("morgan");
var app        = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3002;

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.static("./"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("./index.html"); //index.html file of your angularjs application
});

// Start Server
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log( "Express server listening on port " + port);
});
```

Finally run your AngularJS project in localhost server:

```
$ node server.js
```

Answer (score 4):

Use local-web-server npm package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server

```
$ npm install -g local-web-server
$ cd <your-app-folder>
$ ws
```

Also, you can run

```
$ ws -p 8181
```

-p defines the port you want to use

After that, just go to your browser and access http:localhost:8181/

Answer (score 3):

An angular application can be deployed using any Web server on localhost.
The options below outline the deployment instructions for several 
possible webserver deployments depending on your deployment requirements.

---

### Microsofts Internet Information Services (IIS)

1. Windows IIS must be enabled

   1.1. In Windows, access the Control Panel and click Add or Remove Programs.

   1.2. In the Add or Remove Programs window, click Add/Remove Windows Components.

   1.3. Select the Internet Information Services (IIS) check box, click Next, then click Finish.

   1.4. Copy and extract the Angular Application Zip file to the webserver root directory:
       C:\inetpub\wwwroot
2. The Angular application can now be accessed using the following URL:
       http://localhost:8080

---

### NPMs Lightweight Web Server

1. Installing a lightweight web server 
   1.1. Download and install npm from:
       https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm
   1.2. Once, npm has been installed open a command prompt and type:
       npm install -g http-server
   1.3. Extract the Angular Zip file
2. To run the web server, open a command prompt, and navigate to the directory
   where you extracted the Angular previously and type:
       http-server
3. The Angular Application application can now be accessed using the following URL:
       http://localhost:8080

---

### Apache Tomcat Web Server

1. Installing Apache Tomcat version 8 
   1.1. Download and install Apache Tomcat from: 
       https://tomcat.apache.org/
   1.2. Copy and extract the Angular Application Zip file to the webserver root directory
       C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps
2. The Angular Application  can now be accessed using the following URL:
       http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 2):

"Assuming that you have nodejs installed", 
[mini-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mini-http) is a pretty easy command-line tool to create http server,
 
install the package globally  `npm install mini-http -g` 
then using your cmd (terminal) run `mini-http -p=3000` in your project directory
And boom! you created a server on port 3000 now go check http://localhost:3000

Note: specifying a port is not required you can simply run `mini-http` or `mh` to start the server

Answer (score 2):

If you are a java guy simple place your angular folder in web content folder of your web application and deploy to your tomcat server. Super easy !

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have node.js installed, you can use [browser sync](https://www.browsersync.io/) for synchronized browser testing.

Answer (score 2):

- Run

```
ng serve
```

This command run in your terminal after your in project folder location like `~/my-app$`

- Then run the command - it will show the URl NG Live Development Server is listening on `localhost:4200`
- Open your browser on http://localhost:4200

Comment: Man this command is for angular2, not for angular1.x , also for this command user must installed angular cli

Answer (score 1):

If you have used Visual Studio Community or any other edition for your angular project , then go to the project folder , first type

C:\Project Folder>npm install -g http-server 
You will see as follows:
+ http-server@0.11.1
added 25 packages in 4.213s

Then type C:\Project Folder>http-server –o

You will see that your application automatically comes up at http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Answer (score 0):

You can also setup the environment in visual studio code. Run Ctrl + Shift + P, Then type ctr in the box that appears and select tasks:Configure Task Runner, Then change the task.json file to  this: `{ "version": "0.1.0", "command": "explorer", "windows": { "command": "explorer.exe" }, "args": ["index.html"] }`, save your changes, Then select your index.html file and type Ctrl + Shift + B. This will open the project with your default browser.