# How to get rid of cross origin request block in chrome?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very new to angular, trying to use a templateUrl in a angular directive. When I try to run the local html in browser it's showing me these errors -->

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/suparnadey/Desktop/workspace/AngularJS/angular_directives/baseChild1.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/$compile/tpload?p0=baseChild1.html&p1=-1&p2=
    at Error (native)
    at file:///Users/suparnadey/Desktop/workspace/AngularJS/angular_directives/angular.min.js:6:421
    at file:///Users/suparnadey/Desktop/workspace/AngularJS/angular_directives/angular.min.js:149:48
    at file:///Users/suparnadey/Desktop/workspace/AngularJS/angular_directives/angular.min.js:123:217
    at m.$eval (file:///Users/suparnadey/Desktop/workspace/AngularJS/angular_directives/angular.min.js:137:446)
    at m.$digest (file:///Users/suparnadey/Desktop/workspace/AngularJS/angular_directives/angular.min.js:135:41)
    at m.$apply (file:///Users/suparnadey/Desktop/workspace/AngularJS/angular_directives/angular.min.js:138:236)
    at file:///Users/suparnadey/Desktop/workspace/AngularJS/angular_directives/angular.min.js:20:10
    at Object.e [as invoke] (file:///Users/suparnadey/Desktop/workspace/AngularJS/angular_directives/angular.min.js:40:477)
    at c (file:///Users/suparnadey/Desktop/workspace/AngularJS/angular_directives/angular.min.js:19:440)

**Base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="iAXApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>IONOS iAX</title>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css"> -->

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="base.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

      <main-directive></main-directive>

  </body>

</html>
```

**base.js**

```
var app = angular.module('iAXApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Publisher";


});

app.directive("mainDirective", function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        // tamplate: "<h1>{{name}}</h1>",
        templateUrl: "baseChild1.html"
    }
});
```

**baseChild1.html**

```
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
```

Comment: Can you add also the baseChild1.html please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for standard security reasons that all modern browsers block cross origin requests.

Install this chrome plugin and enable it: [chrome plugin to enable cors](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/reviews?hl=en)

If this does not work, then you should try to run your project on a http-server.
Have a look this answer: [http-server to run local projects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528922/how-to-create-a-localhost-server-to-run-an-angularjs-project)

I hope this will surely help.

Comment: Installing security holes in your browser is a terrible idea.

Comment: Not when you are working locally.

Comment: That plugin doesn't appear to work "locally". The documentation makes it appear to set the header for every site.

Comment: We can define the url patterns. So it will work for all

Comment: how to define the url pattern @ashfaq.p

Comment: Click on the extension icon in your browser and you will see `intercepted url and url patterns` section. There you can add.

Comment: That I got, but my question is, do I need give the local file(base.html)'s path in that or what?

Comment: No. Just give a regex. Although for filesystem ie. `file:///`, there is already a regex added. So just enable it and try.

Comment: still facing the same issue :(

Comment: It working....thanks @ashfaq.p

Comment: Can you mark it as the answer if it helped.