# How do I run an Angular.js page without using Visual Studio?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, bootstrap-modal

My friend developed a basic Registration page using Angular.js and bootstrap in Visual studio. He sent me the 'log' folder which contains all the dependencies and files related to the project. 
I don't have visual studio and want to work on the project without the use of visual studio.
 When I try to Open up the 'index.html' page, its showing everything except the registration form itself.
How do I run the page without using Visual Studio?

Comment: do you have node installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Visual studio to run an Angular app. It's all Javascript and you can run it locally. What I suspect is that your code requires a local server running. If I am correct, then your question is really, how do I get a localserver running?

It's been answered before here: [How to create a localhost server to run an AngularJS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528922/how-to-create-a-localhost-server-to-run-an-angularjs-project)

Long and short, install node.

Then

```
Install: npm install -g http-server
```

Then

```
run http-server -o
```

Comment: Thank You a lot for that! I'm just beginning to work with MEAN
I have  installed node, currently.

Comment: BTW, I tested the app using  xampp, it was working nicely . I have just started with Node now.

Answer (score 0):

Check console for errors. Check if angular and other files are loaded.